# How to build a filter function using Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I've been building my first web platform using Meteor and React.

At the moment I have a database that contains the information that users can submit. We have three different chapters and each chapter contains several artists that people can use to link their information to.

My question:

How can I build a filter system with Meteor and React so I can filter the information that has been uploaded by the user based on what type of content it is or who this content is linked to.

At the moment I gather my information from the database with this file:

```js
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import { Comments } from '../../api/comments/comments';
import CommentsListBeijing from '../components/beijing/comments-list-beijing';
import { Loading } from '../components/loading';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';


const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('comments');
  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const comments =  Comments.find({approved: true, city: 'Beijing' }, {sort: {timestamp: 1}}).fetch();
    onData(null, { comments });
  }
};

export default composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(CommentsListBeijing);
```

At the moment I have a file like this for every chapter. (Which I know is not ideal, but as I said, my first project)

So if instead of just loading all of the information all of the time, how can instead add buttons or fields on my main page so I can load different information into the composer?

I add the information on the main page like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import CommentsListBeijing from '../containers/comments-list-beijing';
import { SparkModalBeijing } from "../components/beijing/spark-modal-beijing";
import Fullscreen from 'react-fullscreen';

class Beijing extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.stopVideo = this.stopVideo.bind(this);
  this.playVideo = this.playVideo.bind(this);
  this.onSeek = this.onSeek.bind(this);

  this.state = {
      playing: true,
      timestamp: 0,
     }
   }

 duration = null
 onDuration = duration => {
  this.duration = duration
 }
 onProgress = progress => {
  if (this.duration && progress.played > 1 / this.duration) {
   const timestamp = parseInt(progress.played * this.duration);
   this.setState({ timestamp })
   console.log(timestamp);
  }
 }

 onSeek (e) {
     const fraction =  parseFloat(e.target.value)
     const newFraction = fraction / this.duration
     this.refs.player.seekTo(newFraction)
   }

 stopVideo(){
  this.setState({
   playing: false
  })
 }

 playVideo(){
  this.setState({
   playing: true
  })
 }

    render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <Fullscreen>
     <ReactPlayer 
      url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HK0MBLLVO8?wmode=opaque' 
      ref='player'
      playing={this.state.playing}
      onProgress={this.onProgress}
              onDuration={this.onDuration} 
              controls={true}/>
       </Fullscreen>
       <div className="barhide show">
    <SparkModalBeijing className="add-spark" timestamp={this.state.timestamp} playing={this.state.playing} playVideo={this.playVideo} stopVideo={this.stopVideo} />
    <input type="range" min="0" max={this.duration} value={this.state.timestamp} onChange={this.onSeek}/>
    <CommentsListBeijing timestamp={this.state.timestamp} stopVideo={this.stopVideo} playVideo={this.playVideo}/>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Beijing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass filter conditions as `props`, like so:

```js
<CommentsList city="Beijing" timestamp=... />
```

And use it in your composer function:

```
const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('comments', {city: props.city});
  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const comments = Comments.find({city: props.city}, ...).fetch();
    onData(null, {comments});
  }
};
```

Comment: But how do I then make it so that when I click a button or a select area, that it updates these props?

Comment: And thanks for taking the time to help me understand this.

Comment: Do I just add an new if statement where it checks the props and then based on those results shows the comments requested?

Comment: Just update the state if the user clicks a button, and then pass the state as props: `<CommentsList city={this.state.city} .../>`